# C++ RESTful Service Router Pattern

Tags: c++, rest, http, model-view-controller, controller

I've been searching around for the past few days trying to find a good article that addresses what I'm trying to do, but haven't really found much yet. Most point me in the direction of pre-existing C++ MVC frameworks.

I have a C++ application with a tiny embedded web server that responds to HTTP requests. What I want to do is create a routing pattern in which I can define service end points and the application will be able to use the proper C++ controller class.

For example, I could define my service end points like the following in a text file:

```
POST     /login        UserController::login()
GET      /user         UserController::get()
GET      /dashboard    DashboardController::get()
```

And have the C++ application call the appropriate class and static method based on the service I'm invoking. So in the case of the above example, if I submit an HTTP POST request to /login, then the Router should invoke UserController::login(). Service end points don't necessarily have to be defined in a text file, there could be another in-memory data structure they can be defined in.

I've been considering something like the Proxy pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern
Or I was looking at this pattern: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html

Before going too far down a specific implementation I wanted to get some feedback from others on how they might go about implementing such a requirement?

Thanks!